# Best way to import Git repository to TFVC with whole history (DevOps)

Tags: git, devops, tfvc

Is it possible to import Git Repository to TFVC with the whole history (DevOps)?

My task is move some TFVC repository from sub level to main.

My plan was:

1. clone TFVC repo to Git repo
2. create new project in DevOps as TFVC
3. import Git repo to TFVC

But not working!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have more than one branch, that's nearly impossible to do or at least it will be extremely difficult.

- git-tf tool doesn't support multiple branches
- git-tfs tool support fetching (not always perfectly ) multiple branch but can't push them in another TFVC (due to how it works).

2. If you have only one branch in TFVC (or a flat history), it could be achievable.

You could use git-tfs or git-tf even if it won't be easy. Maybe git-tf will be a little easier to use to push the history (if it is working for you as it is no longer maintained sinc years)

Disclamer: I was a during long years the maintener of git-tfs tool.